# Reconnect Attempts for CIFS share

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, network-attached-storage, cifs, fstab

I have a CIFS share mounted in the FSTAB on Ubuntu server, which connects to our NAS and works without issue. Last night we had an issue with the SAN for about 12 hours. We corrected the problem and the Windows boxes restored their mappings. The Ubuntu box did not, but we were able to restore with `mount -a`.

I saw options to specify retries in man for NFS but not CIFS. Any ideas on ensuring a reconnect if the NAS goes down again?

Answer (score 3):

The `hard` mount option is (similiar to NFS) avoiding to return errors to the clients when servers are unresponsive. (Default seems to be the `soft` option). Add this to your `/etc/fstab` and remount it (or reboot).

See the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Comment: How will that help with retry/reconnect ?

Comment: It will retry forever.

Comment: Does it? I see no change whether "hard" or "soft" is used or left out at all. Any experience with this?

Comment: No, I only have experience with NFS where `hard` is honored. It is defined to retry forever but I dont know if it does.